# In IOS Can we set image in background of UITableView and UITableView Cell together

Tags: ios, uitableview, uiimageview

I am using`UITableView` and i want to set image in background of`UITableView` and `UITableView` cell together. This is possible that these two images shows together in back of `UITableView`  and `UITableView`  cell!

[Image link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4gihg.png)

Comment: Please explain question properly

Comment: If you  have screen shot of output please share it.

Comment: You are sharing the image path. this image is on your desktop...To share image you have to upload it.

Comment: i want out put in this formate please visit in this screen shot there is one tableview background image and one cell background image view

Comment: Please upload screen shot...

Comment: I can not upload image because my reputation is so down..

Comment: please visit this link i want output in this formate https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.kingsofpunjab&hl=en

Comment: image with no 4 my requirement

Comment: This url can't open in my browser..

Comment: please provide any other link

Comment: https://www.dropbox.com/s/3i5onew6hkw8k4q/Screen%20Shot%202015-04-13%20at%204.22.17%20pm.png?dl=0

Comment: Yes i have done this. i know how to do it. wait i will give you proper answer

Comment: hi...i have find solution..wait for 2 min

Answer (score 1):

For Cell

```
cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_normal.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];  
cell.selectedBackgroundView =  [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cell_pressed.png"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:5.0] ];
```

For Tableview

```
 [mEditTableView setBackgroundView:nil];
[mEditTableView setBackgroundView:[[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"apple.png"]] ];
```

Comment: in this case these two cell and tableview background images will be show on back or only one

Comment: Please explain properly

Answer (score 1):

**Follow the steps:**

1. Create Custom imageView and set image to it.
2. Set that image view as tableview's backgroundView.
3. Set BackGroundColor property of UITableView to ClearColor.
4. set Alpha of UITableView to 0.7
5. Create Custom UIImageView and Set it as BackGroundView of Cell.
6. Set BackGroundColor property of UITableViewCell to ClearColor.
7. set Alpha of UITableViewCell to 0.7

Please try it. it will definitely solve your problem.

Comment: @janisar Have you followed above steps or not. please follow it it will be solving your problem

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can. 
In fact there are more than one ways to do that.

1. Set the background of the table as `[UIColor clearColor]` , Add an imageVieww to the view and supply the preferred image there,then you can set the background view of the cell using the following code `cell.backgroundView = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithImage:[ [UIImage imageNamed:@"cellBackgroundImage"] stretchableImageWithLeftCapWidth:0.0 topCapHeight:2.0] ];`
2. Or you can set the background views of both table view and cell individually using the answer @Rahul gave. I tried it once, but it did not work quite well.

I have had some problems setting the background view of the table view, where the image won't fit properly on the tableView. So I used the first method.

Answer (score 0):

Here's a YouTube screen cast tutorial that I did on this:

[image]

[Custom UITableView appearance](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_K-83AJYgho) Tutorial